# Validator add method hidden field validation

Tags: jquery, validation

Using a form I would like to only validate the visible fields not the hidden ones but I'm unable.

see: **http://jsfiddle.net/gVVa8/5/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#select1").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "More") {
            $("#hide1").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect
        } else {
            $("#hide1").slideUp("fast"); //Slide Up Effect
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.validator.addMethod("wordcheck", function (value, element) {
        return value && value.split(/\s+/).length > 1;
    }, "Please add additional detail.");

    $("#myform").validate({
        ignore: [],
    });
    // check if two words are entered - 

});
```

- jquery validator plugin using add method

  - 3 fields

    - TextBox1 -  validates if by having 2 words ex. hello world
    - Dropdown menu (select1) - if more is selected textbox2 appears
    - TextBox2 is the same validation as TextBox1
- What I would like is that Textbox2 shouldn't be evaluated if hidden.

thanks

Comment: By default, the jQuery Validate plugin will ignore hidden fields.

Comment: unfortunately doesn't seem to be the case here for some odd reason.

Comment: That's because you set the `ignore` option to `[]` which will cause it to NOT ignore hidden fields.

Answer (score 2):

By adding `ignore: []` you are telling Validate that you want it to check hidden fields.  Just remove that and it will work as you want.

```
$("#myform").validate();
```

Comment: tried removing it but it still is display the error.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The ignore option is by default set to [:hidden]; you want to keep this. This way, textbox 2 won't be validated (since it would be hidden). What you were doing is clearing the ignore field, so that all inputs were being validated (none were being ignored).

As for your custom validation tests for specific inputs, check this **[link](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod)** so you can through your own true/false validation methods.

Comment: ignore: [:hidden], doesn't work the field is still checked and error is displayed when hidden. any other suggestions?